# Get string between delimiters from file in C#

Tags: c#

Maybe the question is familiar but I need an explanation in this case.

Let's assume that I have a file called `test.txt`. It has the following content:

```
An example of this line. The line has more than 20 characters.
[sql]SELECT * FROM LINE WHERE aLine = '123'[/sql]
blah blah blah blah...
```

**OR what's about**

```
An example of this line. The line has more than 20 characters.
[sql]SELECT * FROM 
       LINE 
     WHERE aLine = '123'[/sql]
blah blah blah blah...

[sql] SELECT * FROM ME[/sql]

 etc..er
[sql]
   SELECT * FROM ALL
 [/sql]
```

I want to get a string between `[sql]` and `[/sql]` delimiters.

How to do that ? With Regular expression ?

Thanks for patience ...

Comment: Is there only one instance of the string you need?

Comment: **Did you try** starting with a simple IndexOf/Substring pair? Then you can move to something less naive (regex?) in case you need.

Comment: well.. there are a lot of ways. You can find parser libraries on the net for complex things... In your case, if you have only a single tag, you could use IndexOf("[sql]"), IndexOf("[/sql]") and subString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same [solution found in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1717681/251671)

```
string ExtractString(string s, string tag) {
     // You should check for errors in real-world code, omitted for brevity
     var startTag = "[" + tag + "]";
     int startIndex = s.IndexOf(startTag) + startTag.Length;
     int endIndex = s.IndexOf("[/" + tag + "]", startIndex);
     return s.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int start = foo.IndexOf("[sql]") + 5;

var sql = foo.SubString(start, foo.IndexOf("[/sql]") - start - 5);
```

Comment: you need to remove the -5 at the end.

Comment: can you see my updated question ? after `OR what's about` text

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one occurance, you can use common string operators:

```
string str = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\test.txt");

int start = str.IndexOf("[sql]");
int end = str.IndexOf("[/sql]");
string sql = str.Substring(start + 5, end - start - 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

An old question but this often pops up on a Google query about searching for delimited strings. I found a good solution in

[Regex: C# extract text within double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024073/regex-c-sharp-extract-text-within-double-quotes)

in "Bart's" answer.

It's a Linq-based solution.  You split the string using your delimiter character as the split character.  Then you keep all the odd-numbered entries.

```
var stringArray = str.Split('"').Where((item, index) => index % 2 != 0);
```

In my case I was looking for strings delimited by a dollar sign, '$'.  Example:  $WantThisString$.  Worked like a champ.  Thanks Bart!