# Exclude first and last quotation of string in regex result

Tags: c#, regex

I'm running a little c# program where I need to extract the escape-quoted words from a string.

Sample code from linqpad:

```
string s = "action = 0;\r\ndir = \"C:\\\\folder\\\\\";\r\nresult";
var pattern = "\".*?\"";
var result = Regex.Split(s, pattern);
result.Dump();
```

Input *(actual input contains many more escaped even-number-of quotes)*:

```
"action = 0;\r\ndir = \"C:\\\\folder\\\\\";\r\nresult"
```

expected result

```
"C:\\folder\\"
```

**actual** result (2 items)

```
"action = 0;
dir =  "
_____
";
result"
```

I get exactly the opposite of what I require. How can I make the regex ignore the starting (and ending) quote of the actual string? Why does it include them in the search? I've used the regex from [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024073/regex-c-sharp-extract-text-within-double-quotes) SO questions but still don't get the intended result. I only want to filter by escape quotes.

Comment: `Regex.Split` is used to split your string into two and **remove** the matched expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Regex.Split`, try `Regex.Match`.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I was after this: `var result = Regex.Matches(s, pattern);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need RegEx. Simply use `String.Split(';')` and the second array element will have the path you need. You can then `Trim()` it to get rid of the quotes and `Remove()` to get rid of the `ndir` part. Something like:

```
result = s.Split(';')[1].Trim("\r ".ToCharArray()).Remove(0, 7).Trim('"');
```