# Replace all occurrences of the Tab character within double quotes

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

In the end, I will want to replace all the `\t` that are enclosed within `"`
I'm currently on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) trying various iterations of my regex... This is the the closest I have so far...

```
originString = blah\t\"blah\tblah\"\t\"blah\"\tblah\tblah\t\"blah\tblah\t\tblah\t\"\t\"\tbleh\"
regex = \t?+\"{1}[^"]?+([\t])?+[^"]?+\"
\t?+       maybe one or more tab
\"{1}      a double quote
[^"]?+     anything but a double quote
([\t])?+   capture all the tabs
[^"]?+     anything but a double quote
\"{1}      a double quote
```

My logic is flawed!
I need your help in grouping the tab characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Match the double quoted substrings with a mere `"[^"]+"` regex (if there are no escape sequences to account for) and replace the tabs inside the matches only inside a match evaluator:

```
var str = "A tab\there \"inside\ta\tdouble-quoted\tsubstring\" some\there";
var pattern = "\"[^\"]+\""; // A pattern to match a double quoted substring with no escape sequences
var result = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, m => 
        m.Value.Replace("\t", "-")); // Replace the tabs inside double quotes with -
Console.WriteLine(result);
// => A tab here "inside-a-double-quoted-substring" some    here
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/s5s1Jq)

Comment: Perfect and much simpler than what I was trying to do! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
\"[^\"]*\"
```

originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024073/regex-c-sharp-extract-text-within-double-quotes#13024094)