# Ignore Comma between double quotes while reading CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader

CSV reader made in c# language. It works correctly, but I am not able to ignore a comma(',') between a double quote row value.

Example:
"aa", "aa,bb", "cc"

It reads it like

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
aa   aa   bb   cc
```

and instead of this it should read like,

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 
aa   aabb cc
```

This is my code:

```
public void LoadFile(String path)
{
    Table.Rows.Clear();
    Table.Columns.Clear();
    StreamReader file = File.OpenText(path);
    String[] header = file.ReadLine().Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < Table.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        Table.Columns[i].Name = "Col " + i;}
        String row = "";
        while ((row = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Table.Rows.Add(row.Split(','));
        }
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider finding a 3rd party CVS reader as most will handle this for you.

Comment: There are plenty of CSV parsing tools, like `CSVHelper` that do all that for you

Comment: I can take help from an external CSV reader, but trying to add a condition so that this can work. I did it using  stream reader. I am trying to make it work as an application.

Comment: As you have discovered, it is more complex than just splitting on commas.  If you are going to recreate the wheel, you may need to read a character at a time and set/clear flags indicating whether you are inside a dbl quote.  There are a legion of similar issues awaiting you.

Comment: For my own, very simple, CSV parser I used a state machine.  The "inside an entry" state handles commas differently from the "moving to the next entry" state.

Comment: I am not sure about Finite State Machines, But, Can RegEx be used here?

Comment: [This question of mine may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637882/c-sharp-regex-trying-to-get-all-the-tab-character-enclosed-within-double-quote) I was trying to do something very similar in a Tab delimited file.

Comment: `Ctl.Data` on NuGet is a great CSV lib.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can fix this by replacing the Split function with the regex split function

```
Table.Rows.Add(row.Split(','));
```

Should be replaced with

`Table.Rows.Add(Regex.Split(row, ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"));`

And add the assembly at the top

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

This will fix your problem