# c# regex to capture everything between 2 double-quotes, escaped double-quote included

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group, .net-standard-2.0

I am getting trouble writing a regex in C# that basically captures everything between 2 double quotes. If that group contains escaped double-quote, they would be captured as well. After reading the regex wiki I still haven't been able to write one that completely does the job.

There is a coma character between the different matches.

The following string:

```
 "first \"value\\\\", "second, value", "third value"
```

needs to give the following matches:

- first \"value\\\\
- second, value
- third value

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This looks like CSV data, there are a million libraries and packages that handle this.  Is there a reason you cannot use one of those libraries?

Comment: It seems that you are working with CSV (Comma Separated Values) format;if it's your case, have a look at `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024073/regex-c-sharp-extract-text-within-double-quotes

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/bw9Vo2) - is that what you need?

Comment: The original string is a bit more complicated than that but I have extracted it to the example. Also I am targetting multiple frameworks and thought it might be easier to go through regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes it seems to be working just like Arpit's answer. I will analyze what they are doing to get a bit better with regex. Many thanks!

Comment: Is this an exercise in understanding regular expressions, or do you have a practical problem to solve? If the latter, just write a lexer. It's not hard.

Comment: Actually, Arpit's solution is not working if the first `"` is an escaped quote.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the first " can never be escaped in my scenario so it should be alright. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `regex` should solve your purpose -

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*"")|", "$1");
```

Comment: This is indeed solving my issue. thanks for your help. I will analyze the regex to try to understand what that is doing