# How can I exclude the first group from the regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to exclude the first group from my regex so that the result is no longer inside. Could someone help me please?

This is my regex: **href="(.*)(?=(?:"))**

And that for example the text: **fdlasjfkldjfksdj**href="contact"**adskldfjaskfjak**

Now I want this result: **contact**

I have no Idea what I do wrong...

I thank you now for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex: C# extract text within double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024073/regex-c-sharp-extract-text-within-double-quotes)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024073/regex-c-sharp-extract-text-within-double-quotes may be duplicate

Comment: Try [`(?<=href=")[^"]+(?=")`](https://regex101.com/r/pg9j57/1)

Comment: Thank you very much that solved my problem! :)

Comment: @ProgrammingBeginner Glad it worked. I have added an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=` to assert what is on the left side is `href="`, then match not a double quote using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^"]+`followed by a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert that what follows is a double quote.

[`(?<=href=")[^"]+(?=")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dhref%3d%22%29%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%22%29&i=fdlasjfkldjfksdjhref%3d%22contact%22adskldfjaskfjak)

Answer (score -1):

I find this site useful to test out regex and matching patterns http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html

I input your expression and test string examples and it shows the .NET string version needs to be

```
"href=\"(.*)(?=(?:\"))"
```

Note the escaped double quotes.

Groups[1] returns your desired text