# How to get values inbetween specific character

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get the values inbetween the <> and in between the > and next <
Here is my string

```
<MES>MID=13/08/15§13:22:17+08<RB01>I=180.8U=3.87<SET01>ALVU=20.00
```

What I want as output is:

```
MID=13/08/15§13:22:17+08
RB01
I=180.8U=3.87
SET01
ALVU=20.00
```

Is this possible by using RegEx?

I've been trying for hours, mind you my regular expression knowledge isn't what I'd like it to be :-) so any help will be gratefully received.

Comment: How do you know where to insert the texts? I think some symbols have been missing. You can use some markup in the question, for being more clear

Comment: `I've been trying for hours` Please provide what you've tried. That way we can improve it and correct where you were wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't `MES` be there in the output as well?

Comment: Also, if you actually want to improve your regex skills, [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) should get you up to speed.

Comment: You might not need a regex - what language is this?

Comment: @greuze No this is really what it needs to be. Some backgroundinfo: it is a text message i receive from a GSM Modem in the field which monitors current and voltage. It replies with its ID inside the <> and with the values. RB is for Readback and SET is for a Setpoint

Comment: @Jerry no it's not necessary, because every message always starts with <MES> and i only need the data after this tag. :-)

Comment: @HamZa i tried using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717611/regex-c-sharp-find-a-string-between-2-known-values but couldn't make it work for my application because i haven't got those </> tags.

Answer (score 3):

This expression will match those groups:

```
([^<>]+)
```

You can try out in:

http://rubular.com/r/zQ64Z1heI1

You can recover the "value" between brackets "(" and ")" as groups with matchers (in Java or Ruby). Other languages will have different syntax for doing the same.

Comment: Wow that's pretty cool! didn't know that website :) thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
/[^<>]*/g
```

Answer (score 1):

If having MES in the output is not a problem, you can get this done very easily.

Without Regex:

```
string input = "<MES>MID=13/08/15§13:22:17+08<RB01>I=180.8U=3.87<SET01>ALVU=20.00";
string output = input.Replace(">", "\r\n").Replace("<","\r\n").Trim();
```

With Regex:

```
string input = "<MES>MID=13/08/15§13:22:17+08<RB01>I=180.8U=3.87<SET01>ALVU=20.00";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[<>]", "\r\n").Trim();
```

For both of these, the output is the same:

```
MES
MID=13/08/15§13:22:17+08
RB01
I=180.8U=3.87
SET01
ALVU=20.00
```