# How to parse an alphanumeric string to get a numeric value

Tags: c#, regex

If I have a strings like

```
[1] Bryan Mar

John Doe [2]

Mary [3] Cole
```

How would i get the value inside the [] if it is randomly located in each string.

I was thinking of regular expressions but I don't know how to create a pattern for this example.

Thanks for your help.

**Update** Numbers inside the [] is a 32bit integer

Comment: Even if the proposed duplicate is javascript it is a duplicate since the only thing you need is the regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717611/regex-c-sharp-find-a-string-between-2-known-values

Comment: @TimSchmelter Especically as the proposed duplicate question actually contains the answer for c# in the question itself

Comment: @BobVale: I don't see any C# in the question or any answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok I read too fast and read that as c# because change that to `var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\[)[0-9]+(?=\])")` and its correct for c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that using a regular expression would be a one way to solve it. Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var strings = new string[] { "[1] Bryan Mar", "John Doe [2]", "Mary [3] Cole" };

        var re = new Regex(@"^.*\[(\d)\].*$");

        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            var m = re.Match(s);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The expression matches zero or more characters followed by an opening square bracket, followed by a single digit (`\d`) and a closing square bracket and then any number of characters. The enclosing parenthesis adds the captured digit to a regular expression **group** which can be accessed later (in `m.Groups[1]`). If you wonder why the group has index `1` and not index `0`, it is because the entire string is always group `0`.

If you want it to be able to match more than one digit, simply change the expression to:

```
var re = new Regex(@"^.*\[(\d+)\].*$");
```

Comment: That would only match once and also would only match single digits

Comment: can you please explain the expression a  little

Comment: @BobVale that is correct, as per the examples.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen Doh, I read it as a single string including linefeeds.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, yes, I have done that now.

Comment: its having problem with more than one digit

Comment: Sir @KlausByskovPedersen could you make it work for more than one digit number?