# Get values between string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string value like `"%2%,%12%,%115%+%55%,..."`

**Sample inputs "(%2%+%5%)/5"

Step1:

    get the vales 2 and 5

Step2:

    get values from table column2 and column5 

step3:

   from that value (Column2+Column5)/5**

How to get the values from that string 
2,12,115,55 
Also

commas, "+" (symbols)

Thanks in Advance.

I referred these links:

- [Find a string between 2 known values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717611/regex-c-sharp-find-a-string-between-2-known-values)
- [How do I extract text that lies between parentheses (round brackets)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-a-string-of-text-that-lies-between-two-parenthesis-using-net)

Comment: Any effort so far? `String.Split` method [has an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes array of characters.

Comment: Is that string URL encoded?

Comment: Post the exact output you want, your question isn't totally clear.

Comment: Poor quality question. You've written elaborate pseudo code, but haven't shown an actual attempt. Links won't do.

Comment: Somebody downgrade the question , so I cant ask any further question.

Comment: Then how can i ask in future?

Comment: just include some code that shows you tried to solve it on your own and write about where you think it fails and why

Comment: I have no idea to do this, so that I ask help....

Comment: You didn't even give us a clear idea of what you're trying to do. And it also seems you didn't put much research effort into it because these questions are asked all the time here.

Comment: Ok thanks... I will try with my best. Then I will come back with better code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly...

```
var string = "%2%,%12%,%115%+%55%";
var values = string.replace("%", "").replace("+", "").split(',');
```

**Edit:** Actually, I think you mean you want to split on "+" so that becomes split(',', '+')

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the `%` and then split on the `,` and `+`:

```
var value = "%2%,%12%,%115%+%55%,";

value = value.Replace("%", "");
var individualValues = value.Split(new[] {',', '+'});

foreach (var val in individualValues)
    Console.WriteLine(val);
```

Comment: I saw this kind of solution pop up shortly and then removed again due to typos/minor errors, but I actually think it is way cooler to do no replacing at all but just run `.Split(new[] { ',', '+', '%' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Answer (score 1):

```
str.Replace("%", "").Replace("+",",").Split(',');
```

This will do it.

---

Another regex solution:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(str, @"\d+"))
    // m.Value is the values you wanted
```

Comment: _commas, "+" (symbols)_

Comment: No, because there is also a `+` sign.

Comment: no, it wont, read again `values`, plural ;)

Comment: Isn't that what he asked for? Sorry if I didn't understand OP's question

Comment: Updated. I hope this time it works :)

Comment: this is same as @Beakie answer.

Comment: @SidM ya... check the time stamp. Also it's not the same any more.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex re = new Regex("\\d+");
MatchCollection matches = re.Matches("%2%,%12%,%115%+%55%,...");
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    lst.Add(Convert.ToInt32(m.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible parsing the string with splits and other stuff or through Regex:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGetNumberCommasAndPlusSign()
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(@"[\d,\+]+");
        string result = "";
        foreach (Match m in r.Matches("%2%,%12%,%115%+%55%,..."))
            result += m.Value;

        Assert.AreEqual("2,12,115+55,", result);
    }
```