# How to extract an url from a String in C#

Tags: c#

I have this string :

```
 "<figure><img
 src='http://myphotos.net/image.ashx?type=2&image=Images\\2\\9\\11\\12\\3\\8\\4\\7\\685621455625.jpg'
 href='JavaScript:void(0);' onclick='return takeImg(this)'
 tabindex='1' class='myclass' width='55' height='66' alt=\"myalt\"></figure>"
```

How can I retrieve this link :

```
http://myphotos.net/image.ashx?type=2&image=Images\\2\\9\\11\\12\\3\\8\\4\\7\\685621455625.jpg
```

All string are the same type so somehow I need to get substring between **src=** and **href**. But I don't know how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: You can use htmlagilitypack https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ it does a good job of parsing html. It is usually more stable than matching with a regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a string between 2 known values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717611/find-a-string-between-2-known-values)

Comment: char quote = '\'' ; string url=(thesourcestring+quote).split(quote)[1] ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
var src = Regex.Match("the string", "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Using this method will require to remove break lines. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/gGFBtO/1)

Comment: @m.rogalski What do you mean with that? I couldn't understand

Comment: I meant that if your string contains line breaks as it does in question, this method will be useless. and you can check this clicking link I've posted., This should be specified in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you parse HTML don't not use string methods but a real HTML parser like [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);  // html is your string
var linksAndImages = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/@href | //img/@src");
var allSrcList = linksAndImages
    .Select(node => node.GetAttributeValue("src", "[src not found]"))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Does this extract all the URLs from the the html page

Comment: It does extract the url's from the `linksAndImages` of the given `html`

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should use an HTML/XML parser when parsing a value from HTML code, but with a limited string like this, Regex would be fine.

```
string url = Regex.Match(htmlString, @"src='(.*?)'").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your string is always in same format, you can easily do this like so :

```
string input =  "<figure><img src='http://myphotos.net/image.ashx?type=2&image=Images\\2\\9\\11\\12\\3\\8\\4\\7\\685621455625.jpg' href='JavaScript:void(0);' onclick='return takeImg(this)' tabindex='1' class='myclass' width='55' height='66' alt=\"myalt\"></figure>";
// link is between ' signs starting from the first ' sign so you can do :
input = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("'")).Substring(input.IndexOf("'"));
// now your string looks like : "http://myphotos.net/image.ashx?type=2&image=Images\\2\\9\\11\\12\\3\\8\\4\\7\\685621455625.jpg"

return input;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "<figure><imgsrc = 'http://myphotos.net/image.ashx?type=2&image=Images\\2\\9\\11\\12\\3\\8\\4\\7\\685621455625.jpg'href = 'JavaScript:void(0);' onclick = 'return takeImg(this)'tabindex = '1' class='myclass' width='55' height='66' alt=\"myalt\"></figure>";

int pFrom = str.IndexOf("src = '") + "src = '".Length;
int pTo = str.LastIndexOf("'href");

string url = str.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
```

Source :

[Get string between two strings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252615/get-string-between-two-strings-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Q is your string in this case, i look for the index of the attribute you want (src = ') then I remove the first few characters (7 including spaces) and after that you look for when the text ends by looking for '.

With removing the first few characters you could use .IndexOf to look for how many to delete so its not hard coded.

```
        string q =
            "<figure><img src = 'http://myphotos.net/image.ashx?type=2&image=Images\\2\\9\\11\\12\\3\\8\\4\\7\\685621455625.jpg' href = 'JavaScript:void(0);' onclick = 'return takeImg(this)'" +
            "tabindex = '1' class='myclass' width='55' height='66' alt=\"myalt\"></figure>";
        string z = q.Substring(q.IndexOf("src = '"));
        z = z.Substring(7);
        z = z.Substring(0, z.IndexOf("'"));
        MessageBox.Show(z);
```

This is certainly not the most elegant way (look at the other answers for that :)).