# Need help finding pattern with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Probably seen this kind of a question a million times. Regex is like black magic to me, I don't get it. I tried to make a regex I need for a C# application. It's a pattern like this:

`== text ==`

Where "text" can be any text without numbers. With my limited understanding I tried this:

`'== %[a-z]% =='`

But I am here so obviously it didn't work. Any help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1717673/3832970

Comment: `== [a-z]+ ==` :)

Comment: @JohnWeldon Oh thanks bro! Though I see that I also have to account for possible multiple words separated by whitespaces between the two `==`. Can you help? :)

Comment: @Vipar Please read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). All you have to do is add `\s` to the set.

Comment: @itsme86 Oh yeah I got it now. Thanks!